# Display sum from previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sqldatetime

I have select statement like below:

```
  select [Fiscal Year], sum([value]), 
         YEAR(DATEADD(year,-1,[Fiscal Year])) as previous_year
  from [table1] 
  group by [Fiscal Year]
```

How to add after column `previous_year`, `sum([value])` from previous year?

[image]

Comment: [`LAG/LEAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) if SQL Server 2012+, self join if lower

Comment: @4est Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below query for SQL 2008

```
select t1.[Fiscal Year],t1.Value,(t1.[Fiscal Year]-1) [previous_year],t2.Value [previous_value]
from  
(  select [Fiscal Year], sum([value]) value
  from [table1] 
  group by [Fiscal Year] 
)t1
LEFT JOIN
(  
select [Fiscal Year], sum([value]) value
  from [table1] 
  group by [Fiscal Year] 
)t2
ON t1.[Fiscal Year]=t2.[Fiscal Year]+1
```

**[SQL demo link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37baa/1)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+ you can use `LAG` to get the value of the previous row:

```
;with cte as (
  select [Fiscal Year], sum([value]) AS value, 
  from [table1] 
  group by [Fiscal Year]
)
select [Fiscal Year], value, 
       [Fiscal Year] - 1, lag(value) over (order by [Fiscal Year]) as prev_value
from cte
```

Comment: it's SQL Server 2008 :/, it's another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
--to prepare the environment, let said this is your table
declare @table table
(
  fiscalYr integer,
  Value integer,
  previousyr integer,
  prevValue integer
)

--to prepare the value, let said these are your value
insert into @table values (2014,165,2013,0);
insert into @table values (2015,179,2014,0);
insert into @table values (2016,143,2015,0);

--the SQL
select A.fiscalYr,A.Value,A.previousyr, B.Value
from @table A left join
@table B on B.fiscalYr = A.previousyr
```

**This the answer I got**

fiscalYr| value| PrevYr| Value

2014|   165|    2013|   NULL

2015|   179|    2014|   165

2016|   143|    2015|   179